# react-testing-library: test onClick event

Tags: reactjs, testing

My test is not 100% coverage because I haven't tested the onClick event button. How to do it in react-testing-library? Please note that I use connected-react-router here and I don't know how to write it in my test. If I made any mistakes in the code, I am sorry, but I am still learning to test.

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { push } from 'connected-react-router';
import {
  StyledFooter,
  StyledButton,
} from './Footer.style';


export default function Footer() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  return (
    <StyledFooter>
      <div>
        <StyledButton type="link" onClick={() => dispatch(push('/test'))}>
          test
        </StyledButton>
      </div>
    </StyledFooter>
  );
}
```

index.test.js:

```
/**
 *
 * Tests for Footer
 *
 */

import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { IntlProvider } from 'react-intl';

import { createMemoryHistory } from 'history';
import Footer from '../index';
import { DEFAULT_LOCALE } from '../../../locales';
import configureStore from '../../../configureStore';

describe('<Footer />', () => {
  const history = createMemoryHistory();
  const store = configureStore({}, history);

  it('should render a div', () => {
    const { container } = render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <IntlProvider locale={DEFAULT_LOCALE}>
          <Footer />
        </IntlProvider>
      </Provider>,
    );
    expect(container.firstChild).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

Tests result:

```
 app/components/Footer           |    87.5 |      100 |      50 |    87.5 |                   
  Footer.style.js                |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
  index.js                       |   66.67 |      100 |      50 |   66.67 |                
  messages.js                    |       0 |        0 |       0 |       0 |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should get the element what you want to click on. For this you can use the `getByText` function.

```
import { render, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react'

const { container, getByText } = render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <IntlProvider locale={DEFAULT_LOCALE}>
          <Footer />
        </IntlProvider>
      </Provider>,
    );

const button = getByText("test");
```

Next you have to trigger a click event on the element

```
fireEvent.click(button)
```

Then you can assert on the result.